# How to show the ip address the one who logged in my system? the output when i try echo is ::1

Tags: php

how can I get the ip address when using local hosting i use xampp.

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    echo $ip;
```

Comment: Local hosting? not sure if I entirely get your question.. you usually get the IP of a visitor with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in PHP. Your output is the IPv6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1 in IPv4

Comment: You do know that `::1` is localhost in IPv6 notation, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you use looks good. The answer you're getting is correct; [::1 is your ipv6 localhost address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost). If you want to view your own *external* address you should visit your server from an external connection but it requires a properly configured router. The code would work fine if you deploy it on a server that has a normal connection to the outside world; which any random php-hoster will have.